# Typescript 4.6 and Arrow Functions

Tags: angular, typescript, arrow-functions

We recently updated to typescript 4.6 (from 4.5) and are experiencing some weird `this` issues.

for example we previously had a function defined at `#handleUnsavedData = async (event: BeforeUnloadEvent): Promise<boolean> => {` and passed to a service with `this.workspaceService.handleUnsaved = this.#handleUnsavedData`

it appears we now need to define it like `async #handleUnsavedData(event: BeforeUnloadEvent): Promise<boolean> {` and 'pass' it with the arrow instead `this.workspaceService.handleUnsaved = event => this.#handleUnsavedData(event);`

It also appears that we can no longer access constructor injected services before the constructor?
Before:

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  @Input() close = this.workspaceService.close;

  constructor(private workspaceService: WorkspaceService) { }
}
```

After:

```
export class HeaderComponent {

  constructor(private workspaceService: WorkspaceService) { }

  close() {
    this.workspaceService.close();
  }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something incredibly basic here, but i have read and re-read the TS 4.6 documentation and am struggling to find what is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what i did to resolve this, but somewhere down the line i changed something unrelated and this 'issue' went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).